# Library function for reversing the string

Tags: c, string

Is there alternative for `strrev()` in C? I am interested in a function that does the same but it must be included in the standard library.

I am aware that operation can be easily implemented by user defined function but I am looking for a library alternative.Precisely there are few functions take for example [rindex](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/rindex.3.asp) (identical to `strrchr()`) which is more common in perl but still works in gcc-4.3.4,I am inquisitive to know if there is anything like that for `strrev()` since the common reversing function in perl i.e `reverse<>` is not working in C.

Compiler specification: [C (gcc-4.3.4)]

Thanks,

PS:I am  aware of C++'s STL reverse but my question is strictly about C.

Comment: Are you kidding me ? Before replaying please look that web cite, deeply

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such a function in C standard libraries. If you don't mind using C++, there is `reverse` template function in `algorithms`.

Answer (score 2):

**1** .The strrev you are aware about is:

**Using Loops**

**2**. Refer this link:
 http://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-strings/c-strrev-function/

**3**.In **Turbo C** the  *strrev()* library function is available.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
   clrscr();
   printf("%s",strrev("string"));
   getch();
   return 1;
}
```